# Clear previous View and show new View on button click in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have created an activity with two buttons at the top. One button to show "SMS Logs" and second to show "Call Logs".

On clicking "SMS Logs" button, i am dynamically creating textviews and linear layout to show sms logs.

On Clicking "Call Logs", i am dynamically creating another textviews and linear layout to show call logs.

But the problem is that, once if we click "sms log" button and then we click "call log" button, the previously created linear layouts are not removed and the both(previous layouts and the current layouts) are shown simultaneously.

But i want that the previous layouts should be removed on clicking the second button.

Which function, should i use to remove the previous viewgroups or the layouts. Tell me if you need to read my class file.

**Edit:**

This is my Activity's code,

```
public class General extends Activity
{
    String phone, message;
    TextView Logs;
    View layout, callLayout;
    TextView data, callData, line, callLine;
    Button smsLog, callLog;
    LinearLayout ll, callll;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_main);
        Logs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Logs);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        callLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        smsLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.smsLogs);
        callLog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.callLogs);
        smsLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                callLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                       ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                       data = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        data.setText("First Line");
                        data.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        line = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        line.setText("Second Line");
                        ((ViewGroup) ll).addView(data);
                        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(line);
                        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(ll);
            }
        });


        callLog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        callll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                        callll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                         callData = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            callLine = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                        callData.setText("Third Line");
                        callLine.setText("Fourth Line");
                        ((ViewGroup) callll).addView(callData);
                        ((ViewGroup) callLayout).addView(callLine);
                        ((ViewGroup) callLayout).addView(callll);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have removed the extra code and made it simple to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a `TabView`.

But having your current setup just change the visibility of one view group to `GONE` and the other to `VISIBLE`.

[`GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) will make the view invisible and it won't take up any space anymore.

**EDIT** based on the code added to the question

Both your `layout` and `callLayout` are using the same `XML` view. Implement 2 identical views in your `xml` and keep one visible and one gone. This way when you set `layout` or `callLayout` visibility to `GONE` they are 2 different ones not the same. So your `onClick()` will have something like this:

for `smsLog`:

```
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
callLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

for `callLog`:

```
callLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
callLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: On clicking first button, i am creating some linear layouts, after that that on second button's click, i am creating some more linear layouts. here i want to remove the previously created layouts and just show the current layouts.

Comment: You can place all those layouts into one main view and change the visibility of that main group.

Comment: tried it. But it makes the previous layouts invisible, but doesnt removes them, I have used scroll view and on second button click, the next layoutss are shown at quite bottom leaving space for previous layouts which are invisible but are preesent there.

Comment: Change to `GONE` not `INVISIBLE`.

Comment: tried it. but it shows nothing on second button click, previous layouts are removed although, but new layouts are not shown.

Comment: Looks like it's time to post some code. Because I've done it this way and it works perfect.

Comment: Change your code logic. Create and link your 2 layout in the onCreate method, and set them to GONE. Then, when click on button, switch one layout to VISIBLE and the other to GONE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FrameLayout to solve your problem.
 But I recommend you to use tabview.
[Here](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2011/06/iphone-like-tabs-in-android.html) is the link that demonstrates how to develop tabbed applications.
Good Luck

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the problem. I dont want to use different tabs, but i just want to override the previous layout and show new linear layouts on second button click.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/implement-seekbar-to-control-volume-of.html
Tutorial for FrameLayout